# SqlAlchemy + Alembic - how to fix schema discrepency

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I just pushed up my Flask app to my staging environment and I noticed that I now have a discrepancy between the two Postgres databases.  My staging database has an `id` column in the `instance_tags` table while my local database does not.

Three migrations ago I added an `id` column and then later removed it in models.py file.  When it wasn't removing from my database, I ended up deleting it manually.  I know, this is probably a bad thing!  Anyway, my migration file looks like...

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('instance_tags',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('instance_id', sa.String(length=30), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('tag_group', sa.String(length=50), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('tag', sa.String(length=50), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', 'instance_id', name=op.f('pk_instance_tags'))
    )
```

What is the best approach to remove the `id` column?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is [`op.drop_column(...)`](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.drop_column)

```
op.drop_column('instance_tags', 'id')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm familiar with the command.  But, how do I generate this or where do I put this command?

Comment: If alembic did not already auto generate it then you have to add it manually to `upgrade()` (and a corresponding `add_column(...)` to `downgrade()`. Alembic's auto generation is very dependent on its configuration and is not a perfect "silver bullet". Consequently, it is advisable to review the auto generated migrations and make manual modifications as necessary before running them on your database.